# jQuery UI Slider with custom behavior on handle dragging and bar clicking

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've been trying to achieve a custom slider behavior for some time now, unfortunately without any success. The code for the slider is:

There are two things i want to achieve:

1. clicking anywhere on the slider bar will make the ui handle jump not to that corresponding value but to the next/previous step (depending which side of the ui handle is clicked).

**UPDATE**: I have solved this with the following code.

```
var $slider = $('#slider');

$slider.slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    step: 1,
    start: function (event, ui) {
        if (!$handle.data('clicked')) {
            $(this).slider('value', ui.value + 100); // simulating a step of 100
            return false;
        }
        else $handle.data('clicked', false);
    }
});

var $handle = $('#slider .ui-slider-handle');
var $range = $('#slider .ui-slider-range');

$range.mousedown(function () {
    $slider.slider('value', $slider.slider('value') - 100); // simulating a step of 100
    return false;
});

$handle.mousedown(function () {
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
});
```

[jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/ahwbbzcv/5/)

**2. i want to be able to set any value between its steps but keep the step-snapping behavior while dragging the ui handle.**

Need help!

Comment: Both of these are achievable with the API's event handlers. What have you tried and what issues do you have with it?

Comment: @blgt Thanks for the reply. I have edited my question with a small update. As for point no. 2. i am clueless.

Comment: Any idea for step 2? thanks.